# How to extract data from complex Json using python

Tags: python, json

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224484,
               "lng" : -122.0843249
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4237973802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829759197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4210994197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0856738802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How can i retrieve `formatted_address`,`Lat` and `Long` under `geometry>Location` etc. from json. Most of the json tutorials are explained with simple json file.
Kindly help me on this and help  me find some good tutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, simple JSONs and complex JSONs are not that different. You can say that a *complex JSON* has many *simpler JSONs* inside, so if you know how to get data from simple ones, you end up knowing how to get data from complexes

Anyway, think of JSON objects as `dictionaries` and JSON arrays as `lists`. To get data from dicts, use the `key` for a value. To get data from lists, use the `index` (position) of a value.

So, in your case:

```
lat = json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
long = json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
```

and

```
formatted_address = json["results"][0]["formatted_address"]
```

Notice how the navigation through keys occur, and how you get deeper as you retrieve values from its keys

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the documentation for json library from the links: [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)
If you have any spesific questions, you can define traces or code parts to find correct answers.